# Choice - Compare value in input to empty string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Using AWS Step Functions with a [Choice state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html), how can one check if a value in the input is equal to an empty string?

- `IsPresent` may be used to check if a particular key exists in the input, but it will return true for an empty string.
- `StringEquals` may be used to compare a string key against a *non-empty* value
- `StringMatches` may be used to compare a string key against a *non-empty* wildcard (*) pattern

Setting `StringEmpty`'s or `StringMatches`'s comparison value to empty is invalid *in the Workflow Studio UI*.

#### Update

This is a bug/issue in the current version of the AWS Console Workflow Studio. Comparing to empty is valid, but the UI disallows this configuration via client-side validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StringEquals` condition matches an empty string as you would expect.

```json
"EmptyString?": {
    "Type": "Choice",
    "Choices": [
      {
        "Variable": "$.TestField",
        "StringEquals": "",
        "Next": "EmptyString"
      }
    ],
    "Default": "NotEmptyString"
  },
```

An empty string in the input matches the `StringEquals` `""` choice:

```json
{
    "TestField": ""
}
```

Comment: I've added an update to my question after testing. The issue was with the AWS Console Workflow Studio UI and not the StepFunction API. You are absolutely correct that an empty value is valid.